# Run additional block of code depending on if an apex trigger is ran on an insert vs an update?

Tags: triggers, insert, salesforce, apex

As stated in title, is it possible to take the actual "context" in which a trigger is being run and incorporate that variable into my trigger code itself?

i.e. I want to run a slight part of extra code for the trigger if its a newly inserted record, but not if its an existing one being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [trigger context variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) to examine the context in which the trigger is running. There are a variety of examples in that article. For your use case, you can use an if statement like this:

```
if (Trigger.isInsert) {
  // do something on insert (and not on update)
}
```